# Is there a VBscript equivalent for .Net string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()?

Tags: .net, vbscript

I'm writing a script in VBscript and I need to check if a string is empty or has only white-space characters (such as space, tab, newline, ...)

In .Net there is this convenient `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` operation to test that, but I can't seem to find an easy equivalent in VBscript.
I know I could loop each character and then compare that to a list of known white-space character, or I could use regular expressions, but I was hoping for a better solution

Comment: If you care for "Null" or "String" look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/26108809/603855

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such method, i think this is the easiest:

```
Len(Trim(str)) = 0
```

As noted by  omegastripes this approach is not the same as the .NET method [`IsNullOrWhieSpace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx) because [white-spaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t809ektx(v=vs.110).aspx) include spaces, tabs, new-lines and other characters of those categories.

There is no equivalent in VbScript. So you need a regex approach if you want to include all characters not only spaces. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17675572/284240) is one.

Comment: That method misses white-space chars, i. e. `vbNewLine`, `vbCrLf`.

Comment: Thanks, your answer did inspired me to write an function that uses a combination of `Trim` and `Replace` to get what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answer from Tim I came up with this solution.
It's not perfect, and also not the best answer, but it is good enough for my purpose.

```
'checks if this string is empty or has only whitespace characters
function isEmptyOrWhiteSpace(stringToCheck)
    dim returnValue
    returnValue = false
    if len(stringToCheck) = 0 then
        returnValue = true
    elseif len(trim(stringToCheck)) = 0 then
        returnValue = true
    else
        'remove all whitespace characters other then spaces
        dim replacedString
        replacedString = replace(stringToCheck, vbTab, "")
        replacedString = replace(replacedString, vbNewline, "")
        replacedString = replace(replacedString, vbCRLF, "")
        'Other characters to replace?
        if len(trim(replacedString)) = 0 then
            returnValue = true
        end if
    end if
    'return
    isEmptyOrWhiteSpace = returnValue
end function
```